# Android Thread getState() throws Arrayindexoutofbounds 2.2.2

Tags: android

I just read from somewhere that calling getState() from a Thread in Android 2.2.2 sometimes causes this error. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently my workaround is to set a boolean flag in the my custom Thread as false. I new the Thread, check if it is false, start it, then set the flag to be true.